# Does git pull also pull Pull Requests that are not yet merged with master?

Tags: git, github

I was working on a branch on which I mistakenly did a git pull. Now there are a lot of changes on my code, but I am wondering if they are from the changes made on master or the other pull requests?

If it is from the other pull requests, please guide me on how can this be undone?

Comment: What exactly did you pull? Did another user push commits onto your branch? In short: no, a `git pull` does not pull other branches, just yours.

Comment: @CodeCaster there were merge conflicts on my branch with a branch merged with master. I used Github to resolve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pull` command means *run `git fetch`, then run a second command to incorporate the fetched commits*. The second command operates *only on the current branch* and uses the current branch's *upstream* by default, or any additional arguments you passed to `git pull`.

The `fetch` step is typically more interesting here.  In particular, pull requests don't exist in Git.  Git*Hub* provide pull requests.  Git*Lab* provide something similar, but called *merge requests*.  Bitbucket provide pull requests, but do some things differently from GitHub.  So they're a GitHub thing in this case (you have a [github](/questions/tagged/github) tag).

When someone makes a GitHub pull request, GitHub will set up a name of the form `refs/pull/number/head`.  You *can* program Git to fetch these, but by default, Git *does not* fetch these.  Having not fetched them in the first place, the *second* command that `git pull` runs cannot *use* them.

What got into your branch depends on what arguments, if any, you gave *to* your `git pull` command.  You'll have to quote those.  It may also depend on flags and/or the setup of the branch and/or your default second command for `git pull`, so you should provide these as well.  See also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  However, there are already hundreds of answers on SO about `git pull`, so by the time you figure out the right parts to put into your question—by searching SO for details you need to know about `git pull`—you'll probably have found the answer to your question.